# Difference between these two list codes - aren't they doing the same job?

Tags: python

I'm learning about lists in python and I'm confused as to what's the difference between these two list codes:

```
num=[]

for i in range(5):
    num.append(int(input("Enter number: ")))

print(num)
```

.

```
num=[1,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(5):
    num[i]=int(input("Enter number: "))

print(num)
```

I understand the first code adds any number the user enters to the list with a range of 5. The second code adds a number to the index number listed (i.e. 0 = 80, 1 = 75...) with a range of 5. But at the end, aren't they essentially doing the same thing?

Comment: Yes, I guess so (except for the fact that you are losing the data `[1,2,3,4,5]`).

Comment: your logic could be rewritten without using `list.append`, like so: `nums = [int(input("Enter number: ")) for _ in range(5)]`